# Accepting Request data passed in application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to develop APIs and I am required to accept data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead of JSON.

I am not getting how to store and input request data as array in a variable.

Comment: Take a look on this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data , i think that's you need .

Answer (score 0):

Use the same key multiple times, and put square brackets on the end.

```
animals[]=cat&animals[]=dog
```